# Ruby - catch SIGINT to allow finishing of file writing

Tags: ruby

I know how to catch a SIGINT, but I only know how to put the block somewhere random in my code. I need to be able to catch SIGINT because if file writing is in progress (my database writes to a file frequently), it corrupts the file. What's the ideal way to handle this?

**Edit**

In one instance, I handled this by executing my writing function if I detect a SIGINT, but I'm realizing this won't help if I'm literally in the middle of writing to a file using Marshal.

Is there no way in Ruby to catch a SIGINT and tell it to ignore it until it, for example, finishes writing?

**Edit 2**

Nevermind, just figured out a possible answer... see below.

Comment: Have you tried catching it with [`Signal`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Signal.html)? Use that to trigger a shutdown flag.

Comment: I used `trap` in the past... but I just read a bit - are you talking about rescuing the interrupt? If I did that, would I just put the rescue statement around the file write part?

Comment: You need to intercept the signal before it generates an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a rescue block, which rescues `Interrupt`. In the block, I turn a boolean to true. The boolean is checked at the beginning of each of my thread pool tasks and if its true, skips the entire function.

**Edit**

In regards to my edit in my original post: Would the best way to handle interrupts in file writing be to use a boolean again? For example, create a boolean called `interrupt` and at the end of writing to the file, check to see if boolean is true and if so, abort the program? I couldn't use a rescue to catch the interrupt then, but I could use trap, no?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I would do :

```
Signal.trap("INT"){
  if $lock
    puts "Not yet done. Please don't interrupt"
  else
    puts "Goodbye!"
    exit
  end
}

def something_long_that_shouldnt_be_interrupted
  $lock = true
  10.times do |i|
    puts "Writing #{i+1}/10. Don't interrupt"
    sleep 1
  end
  $lock = false
end

def some_other_process_that_can_be_interrupted
  10.times do |i|
    puts "Unimportant stuff #{i+1}/10."
    sleep 1
  end
end

something_long_that_shouldnt_be_interrupted
some_other_process_that_can_be_interrupted


# Writing 1/10. Don't interrupt
# Writing 2/10. Don't interrupt
# ^CNot yet done. Please don't interrupt
# Writing 3/10. Don't interrupt
# Writing 4/10. Don't interrupt
# ^CNot yet done. Please don't interrupt
# Writing 5/10. Don't interrupt
# ^CNot yet done. Please don't interrupt
# ^CNot yet done. Please don't interrupt
# Writing 6/10. Don't interrupt
# ^CNot yet done. Please don't interrupt
# Writing 7/10. Don't interrupt
# Writing 8/10. Don't interrupt
# ^CNot yet done. Please don't interrupt
# Writing 9/10. Don't interrupt
# Writing 10/10. Don't interrupt
# Unimportant stuff 1/10.
# Unimportant stuff 2/10.
# Unimportant stuff 3/10.
# Unimportant stuff 4/10.
# ^CGoodbye!
```

If you use it more than once, you could define :

```
def do_not_disturb(&block)
  $lock = true
  block.yield
  $lock = false
end

do_not_disturb do
  # code that shouldn't be interrupted
end
```